# select.js Select boxes overlapping on open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, select

I am having an issue with a custom select box using a script. It is working but for instance if you start at the bottom select box and click it, then click the middle, then the top it works as it is supposed to by closing the previous box.

However, if you click the middle box after the top one, the top box will also open and this will happen with all of the boxes.

Is there any solution to this?

Here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b4kZj/3/)

```
function tamingselect()
{
if(!document.getElementById && !document.createTextNode){return;}


var ts_selectclass='turnintodropdown';  // class to identify selects
var ts_listclass='turnintoselect';      // class to identify ULs
var ts_boxclass='dropcontainer';        // parent element
var ts_triggeron='activetrigger';       // class for the active trigger link
var ts_triggeroff='trigger';            // class for the inactive trigger     link
var ts_dropdownclosed='dropdownhidden'; // closed dropdown
var ts_dropdownopen='dropdownvisible';  // open dropdown

var count=0;
var toreplace=new Array();
var sels=document.getElementsByTagName('select');
for(var i=0;i<sels.length;i++){
    if (ts_check(sels[i],ts_selectclass))
    {
        var hiddenfield=document.createElement('input');
        hiddenfield.name=sels[i].name;
        hiddenfield.type='hidden';
        hiddenfield.id=sels[i].id;
        hiddenfield.value=sels[i].options[0].value;
        sels[i].parentNode.insertBefore(hiddenfield,sels[i])
        var trigger=document.createElement('a');
        ts_addclass(trigger,ts_triggeroff);
        trigger.href='#';
        trigger.onclick=function(){
            ts_swapclass(this,ts_triggeroff,ts_triggeron)
            ts_swapclass(this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0],ts_dropdownclosed,ts_dropdownopen);
            return false;
        }
        trigger.appendChild(document.createTextNode(sels[i].options[0].text));
        sels[i].parentNode.insertBefore(trigger,sels[i]);
        var replaceUL=document.createElement('ul');
        for(var j=0;j<sels[i].getElementsByTagName('option').length;j++)
        {
            var newli=document.createElement('li');
            var newa=document.createElement('a');
            newli.v=sels[i].getElementsByTagName('option')[j].value;
            newli.elm=hiddenfield;
            newli.istrigger=trigger;
            newa.href='#';
            newa.appendChild(document.createTextNode(
            sels[i].getElementsByTagName('option')[j].text));
            newli.onclick=function(){ 
                this.elm.value=this.v;
                ts_swapclass(this.istrigger,ts_triggeron,ts_triggeroff);
                ts_swapclass(this.parentNode,ts_dropdownopen,ts_dropdownclosed)
                this.istrigger.firstChild.nodeValue=this.firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue;
                return false;
            }
            newli.appendChild(newa);
            replaceUL.appendChild(newli);
        }
        ts_addclass(replaceUL,ts_dropdownclosed);
        var div=document.createElement('div');
        div.appendChild(replaceUL);
        ts_addclass(div,ts_boxclass);
        sels[i].parentNode.insertBefore(div,sels[i])
        toreplace[count]=sels[i];
        count++;
    }
}


var uls=document.getElementsByTagName('ul');
for(var i=0;i<uls.length;i++)
{
    if(ts_check(uls[i],ts_listclass))
    {
        var newform=document.createElement('form');
        var newselect=document.createElement('select');
        for(j=0;j<uls[i].getElementsByTagName('a').length;j++)
        {
            var newopt=document.createElement('option');
            newopt.value=uls[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[j].href;  
            newopt.appendChild(document.createTextNode(uls[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[j].innerHTML)); 
            newselect.appendChild(newopt);
        }
        newselect.onchange=function()
        {
            window.location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
        }
        newform.appendChild(newselect);
        uls[i].parentNode.insertBefore(newform,uls[i]);
        toreplace[count]=uls[i];
        count++;
    }
}
for(i=0;i<count;i++){
    toreplace[i].parentNode.removeChild(toreplace[i]);
}
function ts_check(o,c)
{
    return new RegExp('\\b'+c+'\\b').test(o.className);
}
function ts_swapclass(o,c1,c2)
{
    var cn=o.className
    if (o.nodeName.toUpperCase()=='A'&&ts_check(o,c1)){
     if (ts_swapclass.lst&&ts_swapclass.lst!=o){
      ts_swapclass(ts_swapclass.lst,ts_triggeroff,ts_triggeron);
      ts_swapclass(ts_swapclass.lst.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('ul')  [0],ts_dropdownclosed,ts_dropdownopen);
     }
     ts_swapclass.lst=o;
    }
    o.className=!ts_check(o,c1)?cn.replace(c2,c1):cn.replace(c1,c2);
}
function ts_addclass(o,c)
{
    if(!ts_check(o,c)){o.className+=o.className==''?c:' '+c;}
}
 }

 window.onload=function()
 {
tamingselect();
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to fix the code so I found a quick work around that works perfect.

Thanks to everyone that tried.

*Fix

```
$( ".d2" ).click(function() {
    $('.d3 .dropcontainer').css("display", "none");
});

$( ".d1" ).click(function() {
    $('.d2 .dropcontainer').css("display", "none");
});

$( ".d1" ).click(function() {
    $('.d3 .dropcontainer').css("display", "none");
});


$( ".d3" ).click(function() {
    $('.d1 .dropcontainer').css("display", "none");
});

$( ".d3" ).click(function() {
    $('.d2 .dropcontainer').css("display", "none");
});


$('.d3').click(function() {
    $('.d3 .dropcontainer').css("display", "block");
});

$('.d2').click(function() {
    $('.d2 .dropcontainer').css("display", "block");
});

$('.d1').click(function() {
    $('.d1 .dropcontainer').css("display", "block");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e){
        div_cld = $('.dropcontainer');
        div_par = $('.activetrigger');
        if (!div_cld.is(e.target) && !div_par.is(e.target) && div_cld.has(e.target).length === 0) {
            div_cld.find('ul').removeClass('dropdownvisible');
            div_cld.find('ul').addClass('dropdownhidden');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please note that code only answers are discouraged!